# MS Office default window size for existing documents

Tags: high-sierra, ms-office

Where can I set (or reset) the default Window Size for an MS Office Document?

I'm on OSX High Sierra using Office 2016, and when I open a Word or Excel file from Finder, it opens on a small window, less than 25% of screen size. I can easily resize it, but if I close it and reopen, it opens small again.

I've found answers that involve editing the default template (.dot), but this seems to apply only to new documents. I want to change the windows size for any document.

Thanks!

Comment: Office 2016. Added that info to the original question to clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this...open Word, open a new document, size it the way you want it, then Quit Word.  When you re-start Word, documents should open in the size you last set on Quit.